# AngularJS set default value of an array of radio buttons by a nested id property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, indexing

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asonnenshine/LntU3/).

In AngularJS 1.2, I'm trying to find out if its possible to refer to an object in an array by using a nested data id (string) instead of an array index (integer)?

Here's my data:

```
$scope.sizes = [
    {"dataId":"sm","label":"Small","price":8},
    {"dataId":"med","label":"Medium","price":10},
    {"dataId":"lg","label":"Large","price":11}
];
$scope.colors = [
    {"dataId":"red","label":"Brick Red","price":41},
    {"dataId":"blue","label":"Royal Blue","price":32},
    {"dataId":"green","label":"Forest Green","price":35}
];
```

I want to pre-populate the models with selected profile:

```
var coolShoe = {
    label:"Cool Shoe",
    size:"lg",
    color:"red"
}
```

I know how to set values with array indexes:

```
$scope.myShoe.size = $scope.sizes[2];
$scope.myShoe.color = $scope.colors[0];
```

But I want to do something like this (doesn't work):

```
$scope.myShoe.size = $scope.sizes.indexOf(coolShoe.size);
$scope.myShoe.color = $scope.colors.indexOf(coolShoe.color);
```

Is something like possible? Do I have the wrong data structure? Am i totally overlooking the obvious? 
Thanks in advance!
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is using `indexOf()` to search for a string in an array of objects and it won't find it (and not to mention `indexOf()` returns an index, not the item).

You can write a function to search the array yourself. Another way to do this is to leverage the built in angular filter to search each array by `dataId`...

```
controllers.controller('myController', function($scope, $filter){

    // ... 

    var coolShoe = {
        label:"Cool Shoe",
        size:"lg",
        color:"red"
    };

    $scope.myShoe.size = $filter('filter')($scope.sizes, { 'dataId': coolShoe.size })[0];
    $scope.myShoe.color = $filter('filter')($scope.colors, { 'dataId': coolShoe.color })[0];

});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5fW3x/)

Comment: Works for me, thanks! I'm new to AngularJS, so i didn't realize i could use $filter to achieve this. I'm also new to Stack Overflow...can you let me know if my question and description of problem were correct and/or precise? Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not sure if it is good design you can achieve it with filters. Checkout the complete [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/cevixudu/1/edit). This will be your html:

```
<html ng-app="App">
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js">    </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <!-- can loop true with ng-repeat but just showing first item below -->
   <p>Size: {{myShoe.size[0].label}}</p>
   <p>Color: {{myShoe.color[0].label}}</p>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

and your javascript "app.js":

```
angular.module("App", [])
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {
$scope.sizes = [
 {"dataId":"sm","label":"Small","price":8},
 {"dataId":"med","label":"Medium","price":10},
 {"dataId":"lg","label":"Large","price":11}
];
$scope.colors = [
 {"dataId":"red","label":"Brick Red","price":41},
 {"dataId":"blue","label":"Royal Blue","price":32},
 {"dataId":"green","label":"Forest Green","price":35}
]; 
$scope.coolShoe = {
 label:"Cool Shoe",
 size:"lg",
 color:"red"
};
$scope.myShoe = {};
$scope.myShoe.size = $filter('filter')($scope.sizes, $scope.coolShoe.size);
$scope.myShoe.color = $filter('filter')($scope.colors, $scope.coolShoe.color);
});
```